# Pandas reading html table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web

coins = pd.read_html('https://coinmarketcap.com/')

for name in coins[0][1][1:]:
    print(name)
```

Results in the error message below. When I print coins, I get the complete table, but when I try and get specific info it gives me this error message. I know this format works as I have copied it exactly from other exercises I have been learning from, and have just changed the website. Many thanks.

```
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe C:/Users/Desktop/python_work/crypto/crypto_corr.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2525, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1265, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Desktop/python_work/crypto/crypto_corr.py", line 6, in <module>
    for name in coins[0][1][1:]:
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2139, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2146, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1842, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3843, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2527, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1265, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 1

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Great thanks very much , I see exactly what you mean, cheers

Answer (score 2):

If `df` is a dataframe, indexing like `df[column]` looks for **columns** called `column`. In your case, `coins[0]` is a dataframe, which does not have a column `1`. However, it does have a column `Name`, so to print all names do the following:

```
df = coins[0]
for name in df['Name']:
    print(name)
```

Comment: You could also print only unique names using `df['Name'].unique()`